# emacs command-t behavior

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm a total emacs newbie.  I watched a video which shows ido in emacs working similar to command-t in textmate:

[image]

(video is: http://vimeo.com/1013263)

The issue is I don't get this behavior when I'm in emacs with ido mode.  Here is my `init.el`:

```
(require 'ido)

(ido-mode t)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```

I have no idea what `t` means, this is just what I found online.

When I search for a file (C-x C-f) it doesn't find files in sub directories.  So if I have a file `test/core.clj` and I search for `tc` (for test core) it has no match.

On thing I notice is that he has 'Project file:' in the screenshot, where I get 'Find file:'.  I installed 'find-file-in-project' to see if that was the missing behavior but it doesn't work either.  It only does matching on the filename, not the directories containing the file.

Answer (score 2):

ido 'learns' what files you've visited and maintains a history cache. I believe that's what you're seeing in the screenshot above.(sometimes you'll want to clear the cache with `ido-wash-history`).

Usually once you've been in a project for a while it'll work in the way you're expecting.

If you're new to emacs, customize is the best way to experiment with the various features. e.g. you can `M-x customize-group <RET> ido <RET>` and see all the options for ido

There are other options, like `find-file-in-project`, are you sure you're actually invoking it? Just installing it isn't enough, that won't re-bind `C-x C-f` for you.

Try `M-x find-file-in-project` and see if that's the behaviour you desire.

There's also `find-file-in-repository` if you always work in source controlled dir.

('t' means true btw).

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at `find-file-in-project.el`.

http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/FindFileInProject

It will search for all files within the `.git` tree. I have this mapped to `C-c f`.

Answer (score 0):

the "t" just means non-nil or true. You could use "a", "w", or "t" and it would mean the same thing. People just use t by convention.

### Enabling

If you want to enable something you would have in your .emacs `(ido-mode t)`

### Disabling

If you want to disable something you would have in your .emacs `(ido-mode nil)`